# Storing game profiles for high scores / leaderboards in Redis

Tags: redis

Hey I am currently working on a game that has over 1 Million users, I've had a leaderboard for some time ranking people by their kills/deaths/kill streak and more using MySQL, however doing all these SQL calls doesn't seem to be good so I've started playing around with Redis.

So here are the options I have in mind.

Store all the data with ZADD, for example, then grab it all and use the ZRANGE and ZRANK to find the ranks

```html
put player_kills player1 100
put player_deaths player_2 200
```

However the problem I have with this is that for example, what if I only wanted to go over players that have over 10 kills ? Should I start storing user data in hashes and sort from there ? Please let me know if you have any examples or ideas I could use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the Sorted Set data structure, you'll need to call Redis' [`ZADD` command](https://redis.io/commands/zadd) as follows (not that the score precedes the member):

```
ZADD player_kills 100 player1
```

Once you have all kills recorded, you can use the [`ZRANGEBYSCORE` command](https://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore) to query and in your case:

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE player_kills 10 +inf
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want players with over 10 kills, just use [zrangebyscore](https://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore), like so:

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE player_kills 10 20
```